# Shared source file between two parts of project

Tags: c++, c, directory-structure

I have the following sort of directory structure:

```
part1
    build
    src
part2
    build
    src
```

Now I have a header file that I would like to include in both parts of these projects, it will contain constants and some macro definitions as well as some utility functions, and I want these to be synchronized between the two parts. What would be the generally acceptable way to format my directory structure?

Something like so?

```
part1
    build
    src
part2
    build
    src
share
    src
```

and set up my make files in the `build` directories to also look in `../../share/src`

Or is there a more "correct" way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how I've done it in many projects.
Dare I say "self-documenting"?

It makes it completely clear to *anyone* looking at this what's going on.

And that includes *you*.
Imagine yourself going off to work on some other, completely unrelated project for three/ four years and then coming back to this one.  All those little snippets and assumptions and "understandings" that you work with day-in, day-out, *today* will all be long forgotten.  it'll be like coming to this code completely cold.  It's not nice finding hidden "nasties" in code, is it?  So; try not to leave any for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there really is any inherently better approach.  I've seen a few approaches to the situation, and the best I can do is share what they are:

**Shared Include Folder**

In this case you have one global "Include" folder that defines constants and types and potentially external functions that would be exposed to other applications.  The structure would look like this:

```
Solution
  project1 (library)
    build
    src
    include
  project2 (executable)
    build
    src
  include
```

The make files would add the global include and library includes (as necessary) as include directories so the compiler can find them just like you would for any library.  NOTE: the reference to the actual file would be `#include "filename.h"`.  Automake projects with subprojects essentially use this approach.

**Shared Project**

This is the outline you suggested in your question.  Essentially you have the equivalent of 
a project for shared header files.  The only suggested change I would make to your solution would be how you reference the include files.  Instead of `#include "..\..\shared\src\xyz.h"` I would rather see the appropriate include path passed to the compiler.  Visual Studio makes this pretty easy to do, by providing a list of all the include paths in the project file.  If you create your Make files or use a tool to generate them, then the call to the compiler will need the appropriate parameters (commonly `-I` or `/I` followed by the path).

**They are basically the same**

It's really a matter of preference at this point, and what your IDE has the best support to handle.  I have seen the common files just left in the root directory of the solution, but that approach is a bit too ambiguous since you don't have any context for those files.  The bottom line is that you're thinking down the right path.